# init() not defined - jsTree

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm using an API for 3D packaging
-> (packit4me.com http://www.packit4me.com/api#previewDemo) for 3d preview. The API returns an HTML code. Technically, we could just copy/paste the HTML in a new window to see the tree.

The HTML doesn't seem to work. So I just copy/paste the code from the API Preview and try to run it:
1- The code doesn't seem to do anything
2- When I press on any button I get 'init is not defined'

I'm not too familiar with HTML/JS, but I've tried to change a few things, but nothing worked. I don't know what I'm doing... I've look some website like https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene but the code seems fine.

here's the code from the API 'Element' that I've changed a bit: 
-- Updated --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
        <title>preview</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #000;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;
                font-weight: bold;

                background-color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                color:#000;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;

            }

            a {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    <style type="text/css">
@font-face {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style:  italic;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Italic.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Medium.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style:  italic;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-MediumItalic.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style:  italic;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-BoldItalic.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Black.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style:  italic;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';
  </style>
  </head>
    <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">

        <button style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 100" onclick="itemType='normal'; init(); animate();">normal</button>
        <button style="position: absolute; top: 25px; z-index: 100" onclick="itemType='wireframe'; init(); animate();">wireframe</button>
        <button style="position: absolute; top: 50px; z-inde 100" onclick="itemType='transparent'; init(); animate();">transparent</button>
        <div id="container"><canvas width="1058" height="952"></canvas><div style="position: absolute; top: 100px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 12px; z-index: 100;"><table><tr><td colspan="3">contents legend</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3"><hr></td></tr><tr><td>1 : 2 x 4 x 2</td><td>=</td><td><span style="height: 10px; width: 10px; background: rgb(108, 0, 200);">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td></tr><tr><td>0 : 1 x 2 x 3</td><td>=</td><td><span style="height: 10px; width: 10px; background: rgb(26, 104, 165);">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td></tr></table></div></div>
        <style>src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-BlackItalic.woff2') format('woff2');</style>
        <style type="text/css">tcxspan{text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;}</style>


              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Detector.js"></script>
              <script>
                  var packedBins = JSON.parse("[{\"size\": \"5 x 5 x 5\",\"id\": \"0\",\"size_1\": 5,\"size_2\": 5,\"size_3\": 5,\"weight_limit\": 50,\"curr_weight\": 15,\"item_count\": 2,\"items\": [{\"id\": \"1\",\"orig_size\": \"2 x 4 x 2\",\"sp_size\": \"2 x 4 x 2\",\"size_1\": 2,\"size_2\": 4,\"size_3\": 2,\"sp_size_1\": 2,\"sp_size_2\": 4,\"sp_size_3\": 2,\"x_origin_in_bin\": -1.5,\"y_origin_in_bin\": -0.5,\"z_origin_in_bin\": 1.5,\"weight\": 10,\"constraints\": 0},{\"id\": \"0\",\"orig_size\": \"1 x 2 x 3\",\"sp_size\": \"1 x 2 x 3\",\"size_1\": 1,\"size_2\": 2,\"size_3\": 3,\"sp_size_1\": 1,\"sp_size_2\": 2,\"sp_size_3\": 3,\"x_origin_in_bin\": 0,\"y_origin_in_bin\": -1.5,\"z_origin_in_bin\": 1,\"weight\": 5,\"constraints\": 0}]}]");
                  var binIdToRender = "0";
                  if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
                  var container;
                  var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
                  var cross;
                  var randomColorsUsedAlready = new Object();
                  var itemColorHash = new Object();
                  var itemType = "normal";  

                  init();
                  animate();

                  function init() {
                      var bin = null;
                      for(var i=0; i < packedBins.length; i++) {
                          if( packedBins[i].id == binIdToRender) {
                              bin = packedBins[i];
                          }
                      }                          
                      if( bin == null) {
                          alert("Error.  Could not find bin");
                          return;
                      }
                      if( bin.size_3 == undefined)
                          bin.size_3 = 0.25;

                      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                      camera.position.x = (bin.size_1 + bin.size_2 + bin.size_3 ) * .25;
                      camera.position.y = (bin.size_1 + bin.size_2 + bin.size_3 ) * .25;
                      camera.position.z = (bin.size_1 + bin.size_2 + bin.size_3 ) * .5;
                      controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
                      controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
                      controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
                      controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
                      controls.noZoom = false;
                      controls.noPan = false;
                      controls.staticMoving = true;
                      controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
                      controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];
                      controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

                      // world

                      scene = new THREE.Scene();
                      scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x000000, 0.002 );
                      var binGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( bin.size_1,bin.size_2,bin.size_3 );
                      var binMaterial =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:0xffffff, shading: THREE.SmoothShading, wireframe: true } );
                      var binMesh = new THREE.Mesh( binGeometry, binMaterial );
                      binMesh.position.x = 0;
                      binMesh.position.y = 0;
                      binMesh.position.z = 0;
                      binMesh.updateMatrix();
                      binMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                      scene.add( binMesh );
                      for(var i=0; i < bin.items.length; ++i) {
                          drawItems( scene, bin.items[i]);
                      }

                      // lights

                      ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
                      scene.add( ambientLight );
                      pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1.25, 1000 );
                      pointLight.position.set( 0, 0, 600 );
                      scene.add( pointLight );
                      directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                      directionalLight.position.set( 1, -0.5, -1 );
                      scene.add( directionalLight );

                      // renderer
                      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                      renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );
                      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                      container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
                      container.innerHTML = "";
                      container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                      createLegend(container);
                      window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
                  }

              function drawItems(scene, item) {

                  var is3sided = true;
                  if( item.sp_size_3 == undefined) {
                      item.sp_size_3 = 0.25;
                      is3sided = false;
                  }
                  var itemGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( item.sp_size_1, item.sp_size_2, item.sp_size_3 );
                  var color = randomColor();
                  itemColorHash[item.id + " : " + item.sp_size] = color;
                  if( itemType == "normal")
                      var itemMaterial =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:color, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } );
                  else if ( itemType == "wireframe" )
                      var itemMaterial =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:color, shading: THREE.SmoothShading, wireframe: true } );
                  else if ( itemType == "transparent")
                      var itemMaterial =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:color, shading: THREE.SmoothShading,transparent: true, opacity: 0.8 } );    
                  itemMaterial.name = item.id;
                  var itemMesh = new THREE.Mesh( itemGeometry, itemMaterial );
                  itemMesh.position.x = item.x_origin_in_bin;
                  itemMesh.position.y = item.y_origin_in_bin;
                  if(is3sided)
                      itemMesh.position.z = item.z_origin_in_bin;
              itemMesh.updateMatrix();
              itemMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
              scene.add( itemMesh );           
          }


          function randomColor(){
              var color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
              if( randomColorsUsedAlready[color] == true)
                  randomColor();
              else
                  randomColorsUsedAlready[color] = true;
              return color;      
          }

          function createLegend(container) {
              var legend = document.createElement('div');
              var table = document.createElement('table');
              var headerrow = document.createElement('tr');
              var headercell = document.createElement('td');
              headercell.colSpan = 3;
              headercell.innerHTML = "contents legend";
              headerrow.appendChild(headercell);
              table.appendChild(headerrow);
              var hrrow = document.createElement('tr');
              var hrcell = document.createElement('td');
              hrcell.colSpan = 3;
              hrcell.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
              hrrow.appendChild(hrcell);
              table.appendChild(hrrow);
              legend.appendChild(table);

              for (var key in itemColorHash) {
                  if (itemColorHash.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                      var row = document.createElement('tr');
                      var key_cell = document.createElement('td');
                      var sep_cell = document.createElement('td');
                      var color_cell = document.createElement('td');  
                      key_cell.innerHTML = key;
                      sep_cell.innerHTML = "=";
                      var color_div = document.createElement('span');
                      color_div.style.height = '10px'
                      color_div.style.width = '10px'
                      color_div.style.background = itemColorHash[key];
                      color_div.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                      color_cell.appendChild(color_div);
                      row.appendChild(key_cell);
                      row.appendChild(sep_cell);
                      row.appendChild(color_cell);
                      table.appendChild(row);
                  }
              }

              legend.style.position = 'absolute';
              legend.style.top = '100px';
              legend.style.color = "#ffffff";
              legend.style.fontSize = "12px";
              legend.style.zIndex = 100;
              container.appendChild( legend );
          }

          function onWindowResize() {
              camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
              camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
              renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
              controls.handleResize();
              render();
          }

          function animate() {
              requestAnimationFrame( animate );
              controls.update();
          }

          function render() {
              renderer.render( scene, camera );
          }
              </script>
    <loom-container id="lo-engage-ext-container"><loom-shadow classname="resolved"></loom-shadow></loom-container>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Finally, the whole thing is called like this:

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = `html_code`
```

I should see the box inside the bin, with the legent and 3 buttons, but I can only see the legend and button + the buttons don't work (init not defined)

Does anyone know why I can't see my things?

**I'm using chrome on Linux, the three is supposed to be supported

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call init and animate functions when the webpage is ready you must call them in

```
    $(function () { 
        init();
        animate();
    });
```

correct code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
        <title>preview</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #000;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;
                font-weight: bold;

                background-color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                color:#000;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;

            }

            a {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    <style type="text/css">
@font-face {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style:  italic;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Italic.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Medium.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style:  italic;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-MediumItalic.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style:  italic;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-BoldItalic.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style:  normal;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';

  src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-Black.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style:  italic;
  font-family: 'Inter-Loom';
  </style>
  <style>src: url('https://cdn.useloom.com/assets/fonts/inter/Inter-UI-BlackItalic.woff2') format('woff2');</style>
        <style type="text/css">tcxspan{text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;}</style>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script>
          var packedBins = JSON.parse("[{\"size\": \"5 x 5 x 5\",\"id\": \"0\",\"size_1\": 5,\"size_2\": 5,\"size_3\": 5,\"weight_limit\": 50,\"curr_weight\": 15,\"item_count\": 2,\"items\": [{\"id\": \"1\",\"orig_size\": \"2 x 4 x 2\",\"sp_size\": \"2 x 4 x 2\",\"size_1\": 2,\"size_2\": 4,\"size_3\": 2,\"sp_size_1\": 2,\"sp_size_2\": 4,\"sp_size_3\": 2,\"x_origin_in_bin\": -1.5,\"y_origin_in_bin\": -0.5,\"z_origin_in_bin\": 1.5,\"weight\": 10,\"constraints\": 0},{\"id\": \"0\",\"orig_size\": \"1 x 2 x 3\",\"sp_size\": \"1 x 2 x 3\",\"size_1\": 1,\"size_2\": 2,\"size_3\": 3,\"sp_size_1\": 1,\"sp_size_2\": 2,\"sp_size_3\": 3,\"x_origin_in_bin\": 0,\"y_origin_in_bin\": -1.5,\"z_origin_in_bin\": 1,\"weight\": 5,\"constraints\": 0}]}]");
          var binIdToRender = "0";
          if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
          var container;
          var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
          var cross;
          var randomColorsUsedAlready = new Object();
          var itemColorHash = new Object();
          var itemType = "normal";  
          function onLoadBody (){
              init();
              animate();
          } 


          function init() {
              var bin = null;
              for(var i=0; i < packedBins.length; i++) {
                  if( packedBins[i].id == binIdToRender) {
                      bin = packedBins[i];
                  }
              }                          
              if( bin == null) {
                  alert("Error.  Could not find bin");
                  return;
              }
              if( bin.size_3 == undefined)
                  bin.size_3 = 0.25;

              camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
              camera.position.x = (bin.size_1 + bin.size_2 + bin.size_3 ) * .25;
              camera.position.y = (bin.size_1 + bin.size_2 + bin.size_3 ) * .25;
              camera.position.z = (bin.size_1 + bin.size_2 + bin.size_3 ) * .5;
              controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
              controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
              controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
              controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
              controls.noZoom = false;
              controls.noPan = false;
              controls.staticMoving = true;
              controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
              controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];
              controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

              // world

              scene = new THREE.Scene();
              scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x000000, 0.002 );
              var binGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( bin.size_1,bin.size_2,bin.size_3 );
              var binMaterial =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:0xffffff, shading: THREE.SmoothShading, wireframe: true } );
              var binMesh = new THREE.Mesh( binGeometry, binMaterial );
              binMesh.position.x = 0;
              binMesh.position.y = 0;
              binMesh.position.z = 0;
              binMesh.updateMatrix();
              binMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
              scene.add( binMesh );
              for(var i=0; i < bin.items.length; ++i) {
                  drawItems( scene, bin.items[i]);
              }

              // lights

              ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
              scene.add( ambientLight );
              pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1.25, 1000 );
              pointLight.position.set( 0, 0, 600 );
              scene.add( pointLight );
              directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
              directionalLight.position.set( 1, -0.5, -1 );
              scene.add( directionalLight );

              // renderer
              renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
              renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );
              renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
              container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
              container.innerHTML = "";
              container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
              createLegend(container);
              window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
          }

          function drawItems(scene, item) {

              var is3sided = true;
              if( item.sp_size_3 == undefined) {
                  item.sp_size_3 = 0.25;
                  is3sided = false;
              }
              var itemGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( item.sp_size_1, item.sp_size_2, item.sp_size_3 );
              var color = randomColor();
              itemColorHash[item.id + " : " + item.sp_size] = color;
              var itemMaterial;
              if( itemType == "normal")
                  itemMaterial =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:color, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } );
              else if ( itemType == "wireframe" )
                  itemMaterial =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:color, shading: THREE.SmoothShading, wireframe: true } );
              else if ( itemType == "transparent")
                  itemMaterial =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:color, shading: THREE.SmoothShading,transparent: true, opacity: 0.8 } );    
              itemMaterial.name = item.id;
              var itemMesh = new THREE.Mesh( itemGeometry, itemMaterial );
              itemMesh.position.x = item.x_origin_in_bin;
              itemMesh.position.y = item.y_origin_in_bin;
              if(is3sided)
                  itemMesh.position.z = item.z_origin_in_bin;
              itemMesh.updateMatrix();
              itemMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
              scene.add( itemMesh );           
          }


          function randomColor(){
              var color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
              if( randomColorsUsedAlready[color] == true)
                  randomColor();
              else
                  randomColorsUsedAlready[color] = true;
              return color;      
          }

          function createLegend(container) {
              var legend = document.createElement('div');
              var table = document.createElement('table');
              var headerrow = document.createElement('tr');
              var headercell = document.createElement('td');
              headercell.colSpan = 3;
              headercell.innerHTML = "contents legend";
              headerrow.appendChild(headercell);
              table.appendChild(headerrow);
              var hrrow = document.createElement('tr');
              var hrcell = document.createElement('td');
              hrcell.colSpan = 3;
              hrcell.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
              hrrow.appendChild(hrcell);
              table.appendChild(hrrow);
              legend.appendChild(table);

              for (var key in itemColorHash) {
                  if (itemColorHash.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                      var row = document.createElement('tr');
                      var key_cell = document.createElement('td');
                      var sep_cell = document.createElement('td');
                      var color_cell = document.createElement('td');  
                      key_cell.innerHTML = key;
                      sep_cell.innerHTML = "=";
                      var color_div = document.createElement('span');
                      color_div.style.height = '10px'
                      color_div.style.width = '10px'
                      color_div.style.background = itemColorHash[key];
                      color_div.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                      color_cell.appendChild(color_div);
                      row.appendChild(key_cell);
                      row.appendChild(sep_cell);
                      row.appendChild(color_cell);
                      table.appendChild(row);
                  }
              }

              legend.style.position = 'absolute';
              legend.style.top = '100px';
              legend.style.color = "#ffffff";
              legend.style.fontSize = "12px";
              legend.style.zIndex = 100;
              container.appendChild( legend );
          }

          function onWindowResize() {
              camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
              camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
              renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
              controls.handleResize();
              render();
          }

          function animate() {
              requestAnimationFrame( animate );
              controls.update();
          }

          function render() {
              renderer.render( scene, camera );
          }
      </script>
  </head>
    <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" onload="onLoadBody();">

        <button style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 100" onclick="itemType='normal'; init(); animate();">normal</button>
        <button style="position: absolute; top: 25px; z-index: 100" onclick="itemType='wireframe'; init(); animate();">wireframe</button>
        <button style="position: absolute; top: 50px; z-inde 100" onclick="itemType='transparent'; init(); animate();">transparent</button>
        <div id="container"><canvas width="1058" height="952"></canvas><div style="position: absolute; top: 100px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 12px; z-index: 100;"><table><tr><td colspan="3">contents legend</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3"><hr></td></tr><tr><td>1 : 2 x 4 x 2</td><td>=</td><td><span style="height: 10px; width: 10px; background: rgb(108, 0, 200);">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td></tr><tr><td>0 : 1 x 2 x 3</td><td>=</td><td><span style="height: 10px; width: 10px; background: rgb(26, 104, 165);">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td></tr></table></div></div>

    <loom-container id="lo-engage-ext-container"><loom-shadow classname="resolved"></loom-shadow></loom-container>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190878/discussion-on-answer-by-zanoonstack-init-not-defined-jstree). Please make sure that the answer has been [edit]ed to include all important information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you call function before you define it.

```
foo()
function foo () {
    alert("foo")
}
//Error: foo not defined

function foo () {
    alert("foo")
}
foo()
//alerts "foo" as wanted
```

So try moving `init();` and `animate();` under its definitions